# How to install libjpeg62-dev on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, web-services, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I am following the tutorial https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/ to build a web server for raspberry pi camera stream.

I had the problem: ./motion: error while loading shared libraries: libavformat.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And after I search for many solutions, one said to install:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev libavformat53 libavformat-dev libavcodec53 libavcodec-dev libavutil51 libavutl-dev libc6-dev zlib1g-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libpq5 libpq-dev
```

But I got these error:

```
E: Package 'libjpeg62-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libavformat53
E: Unable to locate package libavcodec53
E: Unable to locate package libavutil51
```

I search for long time but don't find solution to install **libjepg62-dev**.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is, these packages have been removed in the latest `jessie` release. I've figured a way to fix this.

Try the following:

> Note: Never pass the `-y` argument to `apt-get install` when doing any of the following. It might remove existing packages. So, always confirm the installation manually for every single package you need.

1. Add the line `deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` at the top.
2. Do `sudo apt-get update`.
3. Install the library: `sudo apt-get install libavformat53`
4. Install other libs too like `libpq5`.
5. Remember to undo the change you did in step 1. i.e., remove the line and perform `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: The following worked for me:  **1.** add deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi to /etc/apt/sources.list  

**2.**  sudo apt-get update  

**3.** sudo apt-get install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev  

**4.** remove deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi from /etc/apt/sources.list